# Illegal mix of collations for operation '='

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to select data from table 'invoice_data' where the value of company name will be choosen from the table 'crm_accounts' by value of email. I am getting error like

**Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='**

This is my model code:

```
public function view_invoice($email)
    {
        $this->db->select('invoice_data.*, crm_accounts.company');
        $this->db->from('invoice_data');
        $this->db->join('crm_accounts', 'invoice_data.cname = crm_accounts.company', 'inner');
        $this->db->where('crm_accounts.email', $email);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: Looks like your tables have different collations

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what it means?

Comment: Your tables have different encodeings

Answer (score 1):

try this;

```
public function view_invoice($email)
{
    $this->db->select('invoice_data.*, crm_accounts.company');
    $this->db->from('invoice_data');
    $this->db->join('crm_accounts', 'invoice_data.cname = crm_accounts.company COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('crm_accounts.email', $email);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: can you describe it??

Comment: i added 'COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci' so the collation of the crm_accounts.company matches the collation of invoice_data.cname. The collation of both tables seem different and SQL can't compare different collations without parsing one of them.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: It solved my problem but now it is saying to check the version of MariaDB server for the right syntax. How can i do this?

Comment: Could you share the generated query?